# Error: Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroswing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode;

Tags: android, compiler-errors, pdf-viewer

I am trying to create PDF Reader app using Android PDF Viewer Library from GitHub

https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

When I include this Library into my project and try to run the application I get this error:

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroswing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode;
```

Please help,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turned out that I was including both the provided source AND the provided JAR-file in my build path.

I removed the JAR file from the build path (If you have put it in the libs/-folder, you need to rename the folder or just remove the JAR-file)